# .htaccess help for URL rewriting for a RESTful API System

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm re-writing a RESTful API System made for MyBB and I've already finished it, most of APIs I know use to update to make better versions of the API like:

```
- https://api.example.com/v1
- https://api.example.com/v2
```

So I'm planning to use a PHP file for each version of the API under the same domain, for example:

```
- api.example.com = [webroot]
    - API v1:
        - [webroot]/v1.php
        - [webroot]/apifiles/v1 (files required for the API to work)
    - API v2:
        - [webroot]/v2.php
        - [webroot]/apifiles/v2 (files required for the API to work)
```

All the **[apifiles]** are accessed through the PHP file that corresponds to that version.

The fact is that when I try to write the **.htaccess** file to make the users access the **v[#].php** file directly when writing the URL like this:

```
https://api.example.com/v1/authenticate?output=[output]&apikey=[apikey]&username=[username]&password=[password]
```

It throws an error that the API would usually show if a parameter isn't received correctly:

- URL written correctly:

  ```
  https://api.example.com/v1.php/authenticate/?apikey=[apikey]&output=[output]&username=[username]&password=[password]

  Answer: {"uid":"[uid]","username":"[username]",...}
  ```
- URL missing parameters:

  ```
  https://api.example.com/v1.php?apikey=[apikey]&output=[output]&username=[username]&password=[password]

  Answer: {"error":"You don't have permission to access this page."}
  ```

The only difference is the `/authenticate/` string between the `v1.php` file and the `?`. This string can change depending on what the user wants to do with the API (authenticate, online, permission, etc), depending on this string will depend on the number of passed parameters.

I have tried a few methods and even searched answers all across the internet but can't find an answer that actually helps me. They helped me to understand how the **.htaccess** files work. The one that mainly helped me is this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

And the author recommends this tool: https://regexr.com/

My current **.htaccess** file contains the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^v(\d+)\/([a-z]+)?(.*)$ ./v$1.php/$2/?$3 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```

But it isn't working and even after my researches, I can't figure out how to get it working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `/foo.php/something` you would be relying on PATH_INFO - not sure if that is supposed to work with internal rewrites though. I would simply rewrite it so that the `authenticate` keyword is translated into an additional GET parameter.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, it is managed through PHP in the '_construct()' function of the API class: '$paths = explode("/", $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]);', this is later used for loading the correct file [link](http://prntscr.com/ka0adn) for managing the request. Somehow I need the server to keep recognizing it as PATH_INFO, but if there is no way to achieve it, I will seriously consider re-writing the code again. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, how exactly is it not working? My guess would be that after you have rewritten to `/vX.php/something/...`, in the next round the check for existing folder/file might not work any more, _because_ of that "path". Maybe adding another RewriteCond that checks if the request URI is not that already could fix the issue then.

Comment: I've tried but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, tries and time, I've come to the conclusion that is not possible to mix `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` with `URL Rewriting` as suggested by @CBroe.